# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) with React and axios

Tags: python, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have been working with a login component in React which can send the username and password information to the django host 127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/ and when I try to send it, the django server shows this message "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api-auth/login/"

I have tried checking the django cors options in my app settings but nothing worked, also I tried sending some headers along with the post request.

This is my cors settings

```py
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
        'http://localhost:3000',        
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'csrftoken',
    'content-type',
    'X-CSRFTOKEN'
)
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'X-CSRFTOKEN'
```

This is my post request

```
handleSubmit = event =>{

     var csrfCookie = Cookies.get('csrftoken'); 
     console.log('csrf cookie: ', csrfCookie); // set to undefined

     axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
     axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
     axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

     axios
          .post( 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/login/', {
                    username : this.state.username,
                    password : this.state.password
                },{
                    headers: {"csrftoken": csrfCookie},
                })
          .then(res => console.log('Results: ' + res))
          .catch(err => console.log('Login error: ' + err))
}
```

***Note***: I don't have `@csrf_exempt` on any of my views

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am having a similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

Please add `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` to your settings file

Comment: It doesn't work. I think this might be something with the Cookies.get('csrftoken') but I don't know how to fix it.